# jface databinding for javascript

Tags: java, php, jquery, data-binding, jface

I'm a java developer. I use SWT and JFace databinding in most projects. Recently, I've been task to work on a different kind of project involving PHP. I need to develop a web application using PHP on server side and JavaScript on client side. So far, I'm strutting with jQuery to do all the work. jQuery is nice, but not nice enough to provide all the plumbing required to build the web interface quickly.

In desktop application, JFace databinding provide all the features to bind widgets, form, labels to the model allowing you to sync the content of a form to an object, validate the content of the form and provide feedback if the content is ok or not.

e.g.: For a text field, you may bind the text value to the property of an object. Add a validation to check if the text value is empty. When empty, show a tool tips asking the user to enter a value and disable the submit button.

So I'm aksing you, is there anything similar to JFace Databinding for JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

1. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/02/01/2-great-javascript-data-binding-libraries.aspx
2. http://uberpwn.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/databinding-js-objects-into-html-forms-with-jquery-datalink-and-jquery-tmpl/
3. http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/02/mvvm-databinding-javascript-with-knockout-html5-boilerplate/

Comment: jsRender + jsViews are providing databinding functionnalities between javascript objects and the ui, but I didn't notice any way to add validation for the data being bind and change the UI according to this validation.

e.g.: If the user enter a letter when you expect a number, I want to provide feedback about it and disable the submit button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the modern components that support databinding are angular, aurelia and react (sort of... +redux that is about to be dead).
jQuery doesn't provide nice databinding implementation. It needs to manually wire up all prop changes. Probably implement some Observer/Subscriber approach.

Or use some component for databinding tasks that provides enough convenient databinding definition commands. I did it with databindjs. e.g.

```
// Lets assume that there is just simple form (target)
var simpleForm = {
   input: $('.simple .input-value'),
   output: $('.simple .output-value')
};
// And here is the simple model object (source)
var model = {
    text: 'initial value'
};

// Lets set two directional binding between [input] <-> [text]
var simpleBinding = bindTo(simpleForm, () => model, {
    'input.val': 'text',  // bind to user input
    'output.text': 'text'  // simple region that will react on user input
});
// This command will sync values from source to target (from model to view)
updateLayout(simpleBinding);
subscribeToChange(simpleBinding, () => {
    $('.simple .console').html(JSON.stringify(model));
});
// Just initialize console from default model state
$('.simple .console').html(JSON.stringify(model));
```

The full solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rsjpa0o8/5/)